# Own Implementation of Neural Networks in Python heavily under fitting the data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm relatively new to machine / Deep Learning. I have decent experience in using API's such as Scikit- Learn, Tensor flow and Keras to develop supervised learning models. So, I wanted to implement one on my own to get better experience.

I tried to implement a Basic Deep Neural Network Algorithm for a classification problem on my own. I have used an iris data set for this test but, my implementation has been giving me very poor results, it's heavily under-fitting the data, the best accuracy I get is 66 % and the least even goes to 0 %, for every run of my algorithm , I get heavily varying results even after I've set a low randomness seed.

I've chosen a tanh activation function, a learning rate of 0.01, a softmax activation for the output layer and a Standard Scalar normalization on the input variables.

So, I'm wondering whether I'm doing any of the math part wrong, or missing any fundamental part of this algorithm, I'd really appreciate if anyone can run this code and instruct me on possible changes. Thank you so much in advance.

Here's the code:

```
data = load_iris()

X = data.data

y = data.target

class Neural_Network:


def __init__(self, n_hlayers, n_nodes, lr):

#No. of hidden layers
  self.n_layers = n_hlayers

#No. of nodes in each of the hidden layer
  self.n_nodes = n_nodes

#Learning rate of the algorithm
 self.lr = lr

# Dictionary to hold the node values of all the layers
  self.layers = { }

# Dictionary to hold the weight values of all the layers
  self.weights = { }

def _softmax(self,values):

'''Function to perform softmax activation on the node values

 returns probabilities of each feature'''

   exp_scores = np.exp(values)

   probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)

   return probs

def _derivate_tanh(self,values):

'''Function that performs derivative of a tanh activation function'''

  #Derivative of tanh is 1 - tanh^2 x
    return (1 - np.power(values, 2))

def fit(self,X,y):

'''This function constructs a Neural Network with given hyper parameters and then runs it for 

given no. of epochs. No. of nodes in all the hidden layers are the same for simplicity's sake.

returns: None / NA'''
  print('Fitting the data ')

  try:
      X = np.array(X)
      y = np.array(y)

 except:
     print('Could not make sense of the inputs')

# No. of examples and the dimensions of each sample
  self.num_examples, self.features = X.shape

  #Setting default layers

    #Input layer
       self.layers['input'] = np.zeros(shape=[1,self.features])

     #Hidden layers
       for i in range(1, (self.n_layers+ 1 )):

        self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)] = np.zeros(shape=[1,self.n_nodes])


        #Output layer
      self.layers['output'] = np.zeros(shape=[1, len(np.unique(y))    ])


         #Setting random weights

         for i in range(1, (self.n_layers+2)):

          #Weights for first layer
            if i == 1:
             self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high = 0.2, size=[self.features, self.n_nodes])

       #Weights for hidden layer
           elif i < (self.n_layers+1): 
              self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low = 
     0.1, high = 0.2, size=[self.n_nodes, self.n_nodes])

    #Weights for output layer
    else:
        self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = np.random.uniform(low = 0.1, high = 0.2, size = [self.n_nodes, len(np.unique(y))])


#no. of epochs taken from the user
epochs = int( input('Please choose no.of epochs: '))

#Standard Scaler to normalize the input data
S_s = StandardScaler()


self.X = S_s.fit_transform(X)

self.y = y.reshape(self.num_examples, 1)


for ep in range(epochs):


    #Forward propogate on 
    self._Forward_Propogate()

    if ep % 100 == 0:

        #Calculating the accuracy of the predictions
        self. acc = np.sum (self.y.flatten() == np.argmax( self.layers['output'], axis = 1) ) / self.num_examples

        print('Accuracy in epoch ', ep, ' is :', self.acc)

    #Backward propogating
    self._Backward_Propogation()

def _Forward_Propogate(self):

    '''This functions performs forward propogation on the input data through the hidden layers and on the output layer

    activations: tanh for all layers except the output layer

    returns: None/NA.'''

    #Feeding the input layer the normalized inputs
    self.layers['input'] = self.X

    #Forward propogating
    for i in range(1, len(self.layers.keys())):

        #Input Layer dot-product with first set of weights
        if i == 1:
            dp = self.layers['input'].dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in first hidden layer after performing tanh activation on values
            self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)] = np.tanh(dp)

        #Hidden Layers dot-product with weights for the hidden layer
        elif i != (len(self.layers.keys())-1):

            dp = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)]. dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in next hidden layer after performing tanh activation on values
            self.layers['layer-1'+ str(i)] = np.tanh(dp)

        # dot-product of last hidden layer with last set of weights    
        else:

            dp = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].dot(self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)])

            #Storing the result in the output layerafter performing softmax activation on the values
            self.layers['output'] = self._softmax(dp)

def _Backward_Propogation(self):

    '''This function performs back propogation using normal/ naive gradient descent algorithm on the weights of the output layer

    through the hidden layer until the input layer weights

    returns:None/NA'''

    #Dictionary to hold Delta / Error values of each layer
    self.delta = {}

    #Dictionary to hold Gradient / Slope values of each layer
    self.gradients = {}


    #Calculating the error
    error = self.y - self.layers['output']

    #Adjusting weights of the network starting from weights of the output layer
    for i in reversed( range( 1, len(self.weights.keys())  +1   ) ):

        #Adjusting weights for the last layer
        if i == len(self.weights.keys()):


            #Delta for the output layer weights
            self.delta['delta_out'] = error * self.lr

            #Gradient or slope for the last layer's weights
            self.gradients['grad_out'] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot(

                                self.delta['delta_out'])

            #Adjusting the original weights for the output layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_out'])


        #Adjusting weights for last but one layer
        elif i == len(self.weights.keys()) - 1:

            # Delta / error values of the first hidden layer weights seen from the output layer
            self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_out'].dot( 

                        self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)].T ) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            # Gradient / Slope for the weights of the first hidden layer seen from the output layer
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i) ] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot( 

                                                        self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)])


            #Adjusting weights of the last but one layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                        self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])

        #Adjusting weights for all other hidden layers
        elif i > 1:


            #Delta / Error values for the weights in the hidden layers
            self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_1' + str(i+1)].dot(

                self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            #Gradient / Slope values for the weights of hidden layers
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)] = self.layers['layer-1' + str(i-1)].T.dot(

                self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)])

            #Adjusting weights of the hidden layer
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])

        #Adjusting weights which are matrix-multipled with the input layer   
        else:


            # Delta / Error values for the weights that come after the input layer
            self.delta['delta_inp'] = self.delta['delta_1' + str(i+1)].dot(

                self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]) * self._derivate_tanh( self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])

            #Gradient / Slope values for the weights that come after the input layer
            self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)] = self.layers['input'].T.dot(self.delta['delta_inp'])

            #Adjusting weights
            self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] = self.weights['weight-1' + str(i)] - (

                                                self.lr * self.gradients['grad_1' + str(i)])
```

Here's a sample result:

```
ob = Neural_Network(5, 50, 0.01)

 ob.fit(X,y)

 Please choose no.of epochs: 800
Accuracy in epoch  0  is : 0.17333333333333334
Accuracy in epoch  100  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  200  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  300  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  400  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  500  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  600  is : 0.18
Accuracy in epoch  700  is : 0.18
```

The node values of my output layer ( probability values from the softmax activation) are really extreme most of the times, they go up to e^-37; I know that, that shouldn't be the case, when I checked for the weights of the output layer, they were not as extreme , in other words they haven't changed to such a degree that they missed the local minima. So, I'm not able to figure out what the problem is. Once again, I would really appreciate if someone can run this program and check for the issues.

Thanks

Comment: A down vote ?? Well, if you've down voted my question I'm assuming that you guys are actually pros in this stuff.. So, would you mind giving me directions on how to solve this problem rather than simply dis regarding my question ? FYI, same question on Datascience.stackexchange has about 4 up votes and 8 comments..

Comment: I didn't downvote you but your question is off-topic.

Comment: @SmallChess could you please elaborate on why my question is off the topic ?? I think my tagging explains quite a bit that this was somewhere related to machine learning doesn't it ?? I did my best to explain what I was trying to achieve with code and summarizing it with text. I can't exactly understand why such a genuine attempt  to understand a complex algorithm is discouraged ... I can understand if people say its not too clear or bit too much to ask to run the code etc ... but, isn't that the essence of StackOverflow ? To help the not so gifted or beginners in a field ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not about underfitting, you should check your code more carefully.
Here's some advice

1.The delta of the output layer is wrong

```
error = self.y - self.layers['output']
```

It should be `yHat - y`, and I think you don't need to multiply it by learning rate here

```
self.delta['delta_out'] = error * self.lr
```

2.Be careful of the shape. IMO you forget to transpose weights here (and maybe some other places)

```
self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_1' + str(i+1)].dot(
    self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])
```

Suggestion: try to use different `n_nodes` for each layer, you will get broadcast error instantly for cases like this.

3.Update weights **after** you calculate all the deltas.

```
self.delta['delta_1' + str(i)] = self.delta['delta_out'].dot( 
    self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)].T ) * self._derivate_tanh(self.layers['layer-1' + str(i)])
```

`self.weights['weight-1' + str(i+1)]` is already updated in previous loop, which I think is not correct.

4. Try to use even smaller learning rate and larger epchs during test.

Comment: .Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and inputs... I wanted to hear all of these . I will try out all your suggestions, I was confused wit da delta of output layer, few tutorials whch I folwd usd da notation of "Actual - Predicted" for the output layer, So I folowd dem. I've tried with a smaller lerning rate(0.001 ); on avrg dis gave me bettr results, I've also figured out that my weight initialization was also limiting the results of the algorithm , i.e., I only allowed uniform weights from 0.0 to 0.1; when I varied them to -1.0 to 1.0 , I achieved much better results..

Comment: I deliberately did not transpose the weights of hidden layers when finding out the  delta, in my case, where all da nodes in da hidden layers were same, I didn't had to transpose da weights.. all my weights in da hidden layers have da same shape, you're absolutely right dat dis strategy doesn't work for hidden layers with different no.of nodes..